# Error with CreatePipe in VBA Office 64bit

Tags: excel, vba, 64-bit

I used the code bellow for executing terminal-commands in an Excel-VBA. The function ExecCmdOld is called with the command and its parameters (cmdline$) and the boolean-variable if there is a progressbar displayed. The string returned is the result of the command. With Office 32-bit that code worked fine but after the migration to Office 64-bit there is always an error with CreatePipe (showed in the MsgBox) which means "Illegal access to a memory area". Implementing the PtrSafe-tags did not work. So what did I forget? Thanks for your help!

If there is any other way for executing a console command with hidden console window, getting result without a temporary text file and a possibility to show the user that there is something in progress (eg. the progress bar) I would also be very thankful.

````
Option Explicit

Private Const FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM = &H1000

Private Declare PtrSafe Function CopyFile Lib "kernel32" Alias "CopyFileA" (ByVal lpExistingFileName As String, ByVal lpNewFileName As String, ByVal bFailIfExists As Long) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function FormatMessage Lib "kernel32" Alias "FormatMessageA" (ByVal dwFlags As Long, lpSource As Any, ByVal dwMessageId As Long, ByVal dwLanguageId As Long, ByVal lpBuffer As String, ByVal nSize As Long, Arguments As Long) As Long


Private Declare PtrSafe Function CreatePipe Lib "kernel32" (phReadPipe _
As LongPtr, phWritePipe As LongPtr, lpPipeAttributes As Any, _
ByVal nSize As Long) As Long

Private Declare PtrSafe Function ReadFile Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hFile _
As LongPtr, ByVal lpBuffer As String, ByVal _
nNumberOfBytesToRead As Long, lpNumberOfBytesRead As _
Long, ByVal lpOverlapped As Any) As Long

Private Declare PtrSafe Function CreateProcessA Lib "kernel32" (ByVal _
lpApplicationName As Long, ByVal lpCommandLine As _
String, lpProcessAttributes As Any, lpThreadAttributes _
As Any, ByVal bInheritHandles As Long, ByVal _
dwCreationFlags As Long, ByVal lpEnvironment As Long, _
ByVal lpCurrentDirectory As Long, lpStartupInfo As Any, _
lpProcessInformation As Any) As Long

Private Declare PtrSafe Function CloseHandle Lib "kernel32" (ByVal _
hObject As LongPtr) As Long

Private Declare PtrSafe Function PeekNamedPipe Lib "kernel32" (ByVal _
hNamedPipe As LongPtr, lpBuffer As Any, ByVal nBufferSize _
As Long, lpBytesRead As Long, lpTotalBytesAvail As Long, _
lpBytesLeftThisMessage As Long) As Long

Private Declare PtrSafe Function WaitForSingleObject Lib "kernel32" ( _
ByVal hHandle As Long, ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long) As Long

Private Type SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES
nLength As Long
lpSecurityDescriptor As Long
bInheritHandle As Long
End Type

Private Type STARTUPINFO
cb As Long
lpReserved As Long
lpDesktop As Long
lpTitle As Long
dwX As Long
dwY As Long
dwXSize As Long
dwYSize As Long
dwXCountChars As Long
dwYCountChars As Long
dwFillAttribute As Long
dwFlags As Long
wShowWindow As Integer
cbReserved2 As Integer
lpReserved2 As Long
hStdInput As Long
hStdOutput As LongPtr
hStdError As Long
End Type

Private Type PROCESS_INFORMATION
hProcess As Long
hThread As Long
dwProcessId As Long
dwThreadId As Long
End Type

Private Const STARTF_USESTDHANDLES = &H100&
Private Const NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS = &H20&
Private Const STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW As Long = &H1&

 Private Function ExecCmdOld(cmdline$, balken As Boolean) As String
    Dim proc As PROCESS_INFORMATION
    Dim start As STARTUPINFO
    Dim sa As SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES
    Dim hReadPipe As LongPtr, hWritePipe As LongPtr
    Dim L As Long, result As Long, bSuccess As Long
    Dim Buffer As String
    Dim k As Long



    Dim retText As String

    sa.nLength = Len(sa)
    sa.bInheritHandle = 1&
    sa.lpSecurityDescriptor = 0&
    result = CreatePipe(hReadPipe, hWritePipe, sa, 0)

     Dim strMessage As String

        strMessage = Space$(512)
         Dim lngStatus As Long

    If result = 0 Then
    lngStatus = FormatMessage(FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM, ByVal 0, Err.LastDllError, 0, strMessage, Len(strMessage), 0)
            MsgBox strMessage
    MsgBox "CreatePipe failed Error!"
    Exit Function
    End If

    With start
    .cb = Len(start)
    .dwFlags = STARTF_USESTDHANDLES Or STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW
    .hStdOutput = hWritePipe
    .wShowWindow = vbHide ' *** von rkhb: Konsolenfenster nicht zeigen
    End With

    result = CreateProcessA(0&, cmdline$, sa, sa, 1&, _
    NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS, 0&, 0&, start, proc)

    If result <> 0 Then
    '*** Anfang der Verbesserung Achim Neubauer***
    Dim lPeekData As Long
    k = 0
    Do
    Call PeekNamedPipe(hReadPipe, ByVal 0&, 0&, ByVal 0&, _
    lPeekData, ByVal 0&)
    If lPeekData > 0 Then
    Buffer = Space$(lPeekData)
    bSuccess = ReadFile(hReadPipe, Buffer, Len(Buffer), L, 0&)
    If bSuccess = 1 Then
    retText = retText & Left(Buffer, L)
    Else
    MsgBox "ReadFile failed!"
    End If
    Else
    bSuccess = WaitForSingleObject(proc.hProcess, 0&)

    If bSuccess = 0 Then
    Exit Do
    End If
    End If

    If balken Then
        If k = 100000 Then
            k = 0
        End If
        k = k + 1
        UserFormBalken.ProgressBar1 = k / 1000
    End If

    DoEvents
    Loop
    '*** Ende der Verbesserung Achim Neubauer ***
    Else
    MsgBox "Error while starting process!"
    End If


    Call CloseHandle(proc.hProcess)
    Call CloseHandle(proc.hThread)
    Call CloseHandle(hReadPipe)
    Call CloseHandle(hWritePipe)
    ExecCmdOld = retText
    End Function ```
````

Comment: Try this https://exceldevelopmentplatform.blogspot.com/2020/06/vba-shell-process-and-acquire-its-stdin.html

Comment: Hi, thanks for your suggestion. I also tested the way via WshShell .Exec and .Run. But as I understand there is no way to hide the console window and to use the progress bar when using .Exec and there is no way to get the result of the command (without the workaround of using a temporary file) when using .Run. So it would be nice if there is a way of getting the "CreatePipe-solution" work with Office 64 bit.

Comment: years ago I had managed to hide the console window but I forget how exactly.  I'll try to dredge my memory on that.  Do you have a test console program I could experiment on, something that behaves similarly to your console program?

Comment: Hi, the ping command should behave similary to my console program (the original one takes data out of a measurement device so it only works with that specific device)

Comment: I'd assume `lpReserved`, `lpDesktop`, `lpTitle`, `hStdIn`, `hStdOut` and `hStdError in `STARTUPINFO` should all be `LongPtr`?